# How to convert the excel file format xls and xlsx vice versa in java

Tags: java, excel, jodconverter

I try to change the excel file format xls and xlsx vice versa in java by using jobconveter jar in Windows OS
https://code.google.com/archive/p/jodconverter/

```
 File xlsFile = new File("input/test.xls");
 File xlsxFile = new File("input/FileConverted.xlsx");
 OfficeManager officeManager = new efaultOfficeManagerConfiguration().buildOfficeManager();
 officeManager.start();
 OfficeDocumentConverter converter = new OfficeDocumentConverter(officeManager);
 converter.convert(xlsFile, xlsxFile);
 officeManager.stop();
```

but when I try and running the code, following error was occurred

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: officeHome
>   not set and could not be auto-detected at
>   org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration.buildOfficeManager(DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration.java:163)

Please give me the suggestion/solution to solve this error

OR another better way to convert the excel file type in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jodconverter works with Openoffice service. so you should have installed Openoffice on your machine. jodconverter automatically discover the office service and convert document via the service. if you have installed Openoffice be sure the office service up and running.

Comment: I have no openoffice. my target environment is on windows7 and MS Office. Is it possible?

Comment: yes. you just need to download and install open office for windows.

Comment: Thanks mfidan, 
but I can't force all my client to install the open office in their windows.
Is there any way to solve my problem??

Comment: Do the convertion on server side serve the converted file to clients

Comment: unfortunately, my app is client window app type  :(

Comment: Take a look at this answer. Maybe poi api helps you. stackoverflow.com/questions/20049922/java-poi-api-convert-from-xlsx-to-xls